# VirtualFree results in ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER in Rust

Tags: winapi, memory, rust

Here's a situation. I'm allocating memory using the following function

```rust
    let addr = windows::Win32::System::Memory::VirtualAlloc(
        ptr::null_mut(),
        size,
        windows::Win32::System::Memory::MEM_RESERVE | windows::Win32::System::Memory::MEM_COMMIT,
        windows::Win32::System::Memory::PAGE_READWRITE,
    );
```

Upon successful allocation, the resulting memory is cast to *mut u8 and everyone's happy until it's a time to deallocate this same space. Here's how I approach it

```rust
    let result = System::Memory::VirtualFree(
        ptr as *mut c_void,
        size,
        windows::Win32::System::Memory::MEM_DECOMMIT).0;
```

In Win32 API docs stated that upon successful reclamation of memory VirtualFree spits out a non-zero value, but in my case the return value turns out to be a zero. I was quite dismayed at first, so I decided to get right into the weeds to further investigate the problem. During my investigation I found out that calling GetLastError would give me a more detailed explanation of what I might have done wrong. The value this function ended up returning was 0x57, i.e ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. As that issue has been a primary source of majority of negative emotions for quite a while, I've had a lot of time to experiment with input values to these precious functions. And here's a thing. The setting I started describing the problem with functions perfectly when I'm running tests in release mode, but is completely off the table when it comes to debug mode. When I pass 0 as a second argument to VirtualFree, and MEM_RELEASE as a third one, it ends up crashing in both modes. So, how do I escape this nightmare and finally resolve the issue? 
**UPD**
I apologize for the lack of context. So, the problem occurs when I'm running the following test

```
#[test]
fn stress() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let seed: u64 = rng.gen();
    let seed = seed % 10000;
    run_stress(seed);
}

fn run_stress(seed: u64) {
    let mut a = Dlmalloc::new();

    println!("++++++++++++++++++++++ seed = {}\n", seed);
    let mut rng = StdRng::seed_from_u64(seed);
    let mut ptrs = Vec::new();
    let max = if cfg!(test_lots) { 1_000_000 } else { 10_000 };
    unsafe {
        for _k in 0..max {
            let free = !ptrs.is_empty()
                && ((ptrs.len() < 10_000 && rng.gen_bool(1f64 / 3f64)) || rng.gen());
            if free {
                let idx = rng.gen_range(0, ptrs.len());
                let (ptr, size, align) = ptrs.swap_remove(idx);
                println!("ptr: {:p}, size = {}", ptr, size);
                a.free(ptr, size, align); // crashes right after the call to this function
                continue;
            }

            if !ptrs.is_empty() && rng.gen_bool(1f64 / 100f64) {
                let idx = rng.gen_range(0, ptrs.len());
                let (ptr, size, align) = ptrs.swap_remove(idx);
                let new_size = if rng.gen() {
                    rng.gen_range(size, size * 2)
                } else if size > 10 {
                    rng.gen_range(size / 2, size)
                } else {
                    continue;
                };
                let mut tmp = Vec::new();
                for i in 0..cmp::min(size, new_size) {
                    tmp.push(*ptr.add(i));
                }
                let ptr = a.realloc(ptr, size, align, new_size);
                assert!(!ptr.is_null());
                for (i, byte) in tmp.iter().enumerate() {
                    assert_eq!(*byte, *ptr.add(i));
                }
                ptrs.push((ptr, new_size, align));
            }

            let size = if rng.gen() {
                rng.gen_range(1, 128)
            } else {
                rng.gen_range(1, 128 * 1024)
            };
            let align = if rng.gen_bool(1f64 / 10f64) {
                1 << rng.gen_range(3, 8)
            } else {
                8
            };

            let zero = rng.gen_bool(1f64 / 50f64);
            let ptr = if zero {
                a.calloc(size, align)
            } else {
                a.malloc(size, align)
            };
            for i in 0..size {
                if zero {
                    assert_eq!(*ptr.add(i), 0);
                }
                *ptr.add(i) = 0xce;
            }
            ptrs.push((ptr, size, align));
        }
    }
}
```

I should point out that it doesn't crash on a particular iteration -- this number always changes.

This is the excerpt from the [dlmalloc-rust](https://github.com/gear-tech/dlmalloc-rust) crate.

The crate I'm using for interacting with winapi is [windows-rs](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs)

Here's an implementation of `free`

```rust
pub unsafe fn free(ptr: *mut u8, size: usize) -> bool {
    let result = System::Memory::VirtualFree(
        ptr as *mut c_void,
        0,
        windows::Win32::System::Memory::MEM_RELEASE).0;

    if result == 0 {
        let cause = windows::Win32::Foundation::GetLastError().0;
        dlverbose!("{}", cause);
    }

    result != 0
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by it "crashing" when you pass in `0` and `MEM_RELEASE` for the 2nd and 3rd arguments? Do you mean `VirtualFree()` returns `0`, and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` like the other case?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It needs to include the crate you are using to access the Windows API, the expected behavior and the observed behavior. It's certainly reasonable to cut down no the prose; that's really just noise.

Comment: @BrianBowman when I'm calling VirtualFree with 0 and MEM_RELEASE, GetLastError's output changes to 0x1e7, i.e ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS

Comment: @IInspectable see the UPD section of the question.

Comment: We still cannot see the code that calls `VirtualFree`, nor how it evaluates its result, when or under which conditions it calls `GetLastError`, nor which crate the code is using. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable edited the question once again. I already wrote that it uses windows-rs crate.

Comment: That's still not a [mcve]. Though, honestly, if your allocator implementation will always allocate in multiples of 4k, you might want to look for a different allocator implementation altogether. Linux-centric code that then gets transliterated to compile for Windows is generally complete garbage. `dlmalloc` doesn't appear to be an exception here. It's not like Windows didn't come with a complete [heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/) implementation, ready to be used...

Comment: @IInspectable thank you. The thing is that I couldn't reproduce the problem when I created a new project from scratch, and it's still not clear under what circumstances it crashes. Debugger helped me to recognize the source of a problem, but not the reason of it. Well, I'll probably keep looking for some implementation of dlmalloc in windows.

Comment: Why do you even *want* a `dlmalloc` implementation? If you need to allocate memory without relying on the Standard Library, just use the heap API I linked to previously. If you don't need control over the specific heap that's being used, use Windows' global allocator (e.g. [`CoTaskMemAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemalloc)). As a rule of thumb: For anything that Linux/POSIX does one way, with extremely high probability there's a superior way in Windows.

Comment: There're couple reasons to that, one of which is just learning the innerworkings of the allocator. Another reason is that I need to get it working in windows, as this dlmalloc-rs crate lacks support for the latter.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with windows-rs VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree. Did you find out what was wrong?